# powershell invoke-restmethod environmental variable in url

Tags: rest, powershell, scripting, invoke

I am trying to make a very simple script that can delete a folder using Invoke-Restmethod. It works fine if I write the exact folder destination, but if I want to add stuff like $env:computername it simply returns empty

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri http://rm44:8081/conf.fapi-1.4.0/client/machine/$env:computername/ -Method DELETE
```

This would return http://rm44:8081/conf.fapi-1.4.0/client/machine// instead of my actual computername, which I understand is a string, but it is not read as one.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you create the `Uri` first and pass it as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As arco444 said, you should define the URI in a variable and pass it to the Invoke-RestMethod. You're trying to insert a variable ($env:computername) in a place where only a literal string is allowed.

This code should work for you:

```
$URI = "http://rm44:8081/conf.fapi-1.4.0/client/machine/$env:computername"
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri $URI -Method DELETE
```